# Struts2 & jquery - custom pagination - how to go to page2 without hitting the db again

Tags: struts2

thanks in advance for any input. I am using struts2 and jquery in this app.

I tried to use displaytag for pagination but my tables have images and there wasn't a way I could make displaytag work with images.

So now I have custom coded pagination which uses `<s:subset>` which works great so far except that I don't know how to make it go to another page.

Basically in `<s:subset>` I just want to change the start attribute and then refresh my JSP. My code evaluates the start attribute correctly with a given page number.

My s:subset tag is like below,

```
<s:subset source="pageableList.pagedList" count="pageableList.pageSize" start="pageableList.start"  > 
            <s:iterator>
```

I think I want to use `<s:url>` to display my clickable page numbers but I'm having trouble there.

I have my page numbers in a list (which I evaluate in my action class right after my search completes), then in my JSP where I need to display the clickable page numbers, I iterate through the list, displaying the page numbers like below -

```
<s:iterator value="pageNumList" > | <a href='#'> <s:property/> </a> </s:iterator>
```

I guess I need to pass the clicked value of page number to the action class, then since the search results are in a list in the action class, without hitting the database again just display the results page with the new value of start attribute.

Any ideas how I might do that? I have been considering using a Decider attribute with `<s:subset>` but maybe there is a simpler way?

Thanks again for any input.

Regards,
veeCan

Comment: What is your aversion to hitting the db twice?

Comment: umm, I was basically trying to get it off of my results bean which is in the action class since it is already populated with all the rows. I guess I can pull just the required number of rows from the database then.. is that a good idea though? I mean, too many db hits ?

Comment: It all depends on your application. Time it, if it does not meet requirements you'll need to do something.  But on the other hand having your memory filled with images the user may never display might not be good, but then again depends on your application if there are only a few and you have the resources they could just live in memory.

Comment: Thanks Quaternion for your input.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you do not want to hit your DB again, cache the results of the initial query in RAM in your Action class (reference a static cache somewhere).  Also, you don't have to go with a cache-all-or-nothing approach -- you can cache the first N pages and then when you near the end of the cache, fetch the rest.  If you do it right, you can maintain minimum RAM footprint but preserve a snappy user experience that leverages user think time (depends on your app).

Comment: Thanks Kelly for your input. I am using iBatis so am now considering pagination using that; yes storing a huge list in memory is not a good idea; I guess I was thinking I could get away with that since it is a tiny app :) but you never know.  Thanks again.